# qooxdoo: Building scss using scss.py

Tags: sass, qooxdoo

I tried to compile scss to css by scss.py.
I finally found that I had to create the folder structure qooxdoo-3.0-sdk/tool/pylib/scss/**sass/frameworks** and copy qooxdoo-3.0-sdk/framework/source/resource/qx/mobile/scss/* into it.
Do I have to add some path reference?

```
"compile-css" :
{
    "let" :
    {
        "SCSS_CMD" : "${PYTHON_CMD} ${QOOXDOO_PATH}/tool/bin/scss.py"
    },
    "shell" :
    {
        "command" :
        [
            "${SCSS_CMD} --output=${QOOXDOO_PATH}/framework/source/qx/mobile/css/ios.css ${QOOXDOO_PATH}/framework/source/resource/qx/mobile/scss/ios.scss"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "path reference". Normally you won't have to create the `sass/frameworks` directory path and copy files manually. You would be working and generating files in your app directories only.

Can you provide more context and what you are trying to achieve? :)

I assume you created a mobile app (`./qooxdoo-3.0-sdk/create-application.py -n myApp -t mobile`). This provides you already with a watch job for scss (`watch-scss`) [1] in your `config.json`. So there you can see how we use `tool/bin/scss.py` [2]. This is also covered in the dedicated manual page, which you might have found already [3].

- [1] http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0/pages/tool/generator/default_jobs_actions.html#watch-scss
- [2] https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/component/skeleton/mobile/config.tmpl.json
- [3] http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0/pages/mobile/theming.html

Comment: With "path reference" I meant the '--load-path' :).
Found that part in [2].
Thanks a lot.